# how can i receive then send then back to receive in multithreading udp sockets in python?

Tags: python, sockets, udp, python-multithreading

I'm simultating a simplified wireless network, and i want to represent each node with a thread and a socket that send and receive, the problem is when i did a sample of 2 threads, the first message is not received

I tried to test if the first thread is sending using another receiver and it was working, and than tried to test if the second thread receiver is working and it was working

```py
import socket
import time
import threading
import struct
import sys


class PingerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, node):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.node = node

    def run(self):
        print('start thread', self.node)
        multicast_group = '224.3.29.71'  # for listner
        server_address = ('', 10000)

        # Create the socket
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

        # Bind to the server address
        sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        sock.bind(server_address)

        # Tell the operating system to add the socket to the multicast group
        # on all interfaces.
        group = socket.inet_aton(multicast_group)
        mreq = struct.pack('4sL', group, socket.INADDR_ANY)
        sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)

        # Receive loop
        # begin as listner
        while True:
            msg1= '\n node' + str(self.node) + ' waiting to receive message'
            print(msg1)
            x = self.node
            sock.settimeout(x)

            try:

                data, address = sock.recvfrom(1024)

            except socket.timeout:
                break;

            if ((data.decode('utf-8'))[0] != str(self.node)):
                msg2 = '\n!node' + str(self.node) + 'received: ' + data.decode('utf-8')
                print(msg2)


        # transform to sender
        message = str(self.node) + ' first msg'
        msg3 = '\nsending node' + message
        print(msg3)
        multicast_group = ('224.3.29.71', 10000)  # pour sender

        sock.sendto(message.encode(), multicast_group)

        # back to listner
        sock.settimeout(None)
        printing = True #boolean to control print function
        while True:
            if printing == True:
                msg4 = '\n node' + str(self.node) + ' waiting to receive message'
                print(msg4)
                printage = False
                sock.settimeout(None)
            try:
                data, address = sock.recvfrom(1024)
            except socket.timeout:
                break;

            if ((data.decode('utf-8'))[0] != str(self.node)):#only print msg if you are not the sender
                msg5 = '\n!!!!node' + str(self.node) + ' received: ' +data.decode('utf-8')
                printing = True
                print(msg5)


a = PingerThread(8)
a.start()

b = PingerThread(2)
b.start()
```

Comment: I'm new to sockets and multithreading so sorry if you find basic mistakes

Comment: ***"each node with a thread and a socket that send and receive"***: Rethink your approach, you should use per **node** one `Thread` to **send** and another `Thread` to **receive**.